# Possibly negative indices in a CUDA thread block?

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a quite simple 1D CUDA kernel doing a inclusive sum, that is, if we have a input 1D array

[ x_0, x_1, x_2,..., x_n-1 ]

the output would be

[ x_0, x_0+x_1, x_0+x_1+x_2, ..., x_0+x_1+...x_n-1 ].

The kernel shown below actually does not completely finish this job, on the other hand it finishes its job within each block. Anyway my question is not about how I can completely implement the inclusive sum, but I think there is a possible negative-indexing error during thread calculation.

```
__global__ void parallel_scan_inefficient(float* input, float* output){
// num_threads and max_i are globalled defined  
__shared__ float temp[num_threads];

int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;//global index

if (i<max_i)
{
    temp[threadIdx.x]=input[i];
}

for (unsigned int stride=1;stride<=threadIdx.x; stride*=2)
{
    __syncthreads();
    temp[threadIdx.x]+=temp[threadIdx.x-stride];
}

output[i]=temp[threadIdx.x];
```

}

This piece of program is in fact from Hwu&Kirk's textbook "Programming Massively Parallel Processors" Chapter 9 pp.203.

So as you can see in the for-loop

```
for (unsigned int stride=1;stride<=threadIdx.x; stride*=2)
{
    __syncthreads();
    temp[threadIdx.x]+=temp[threadIdx.x-stride];
}
```

since "threadIdx.x" starts from 0 for each block, but "stride" starts from 1. Wouldn't we see for example temp[-1] for the first element in a block ? Also after one iteration, "stride" then becomes 2 and we will see temp[-2] for threadIdx.x=0 ?

This doesn't quite make sense to me, though CUDA compiler doesn't report any errors - I ran cuda-memcheck for this kernel and it is still fine. Also the results are right (of course it is right for each block, as I said this kernel only partially finishes the inclusive sum)

I reckon I might make a very stupid mistake but I just couldn't spot it. Any light would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a code like this:

```
for (unsigned int stride=1;stride<=threadIdx.x; stride*=2)
{
    __syncthreads();
    temp[threadIdx.x]+=temp[threadIdx.x-stride];
}
```

Then for thread where threadIdx.x == 0 the for loop will be skipped entirely. Try running the following code in main:

```
for (unsigned int stride=1;stride<=0; stride*=2)
{
    cout << "I am running" << endl;
}
```

And you'll see there is nothing in the console.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Seems indeed I made a very stupid mistake - now everything looks so obvious lol...